# How do I retrieve the TouchUpInside return on a button (MonoTouch)?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

*Information*

I am using Xamarin Studio and Xcode.

My two buttons 'IncreaseButton' & 'DecreaseButton' both have their sent events "TouchUpInside" attached to my IBAction 'buttonClick'.

The code below will produce 2 errors on build in the partial void buttonClick function; however, my question is how can I not produce those 2 errors while achieving what I kinda what to achieve in the code below (if that makes any sense).

Thanks.

```
using System; 
using System.Drawing; 
using MonoTouch.Foundation; 
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Allah
{
public partial class AllahViewController : UIViewController
{
    protected int clickCount;

    public AllahViewController () : base ("AllahViewController", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        this.IncreaseButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            this.clickCount++;
        };

        this.DecreaseButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            this.clickCount--;
        }; 

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    partial void buttonClick (NSObject sender)
    {
        if (this.IncreaseButton.TouchUpInside == true)
        {
            this.CountLabel.Text = clickCount.ToString();
        }

        if (this.DecreaseButton.TouchUpInside == true)
        {
            this.CountLabel.Text = clickCount.ToString();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: AllahViewController? interesting name for a view controller ....

Comment: @SamBudda, I knew someone was going to comment on that...honestly, I just put random names as I am fresh to this OSX programming scheme. Please help though.

Comment: Is this a school project? I haven't seen this kind of iOS coding before. So I am not sure I can help or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Not a school project. If you read, I am using Xamarin Studio (for the programming using c#) and this 'IDE' uses Xcode for the UI. If you check the partial void buttonClick function, 2 errors arise on the build pointing to the two if functions within in (as those statements are not possible); however, I am wondering on how to do those functions without the errors.

Comment: You do not need to wire up to buttonClick IBAction if you are already using TouchUpInside... just move your Label updating code to both TouchUpInside event as the last line and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write it like this:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

partial void decreaseButtonClick (NSObject sender)
{
    clickCount--;
    this.CountLabel.Text = clickCount.ToString();       
}

partial void increaseButtonClick (NSObject sender)
{
    clickCount++;
    this.CountLabel.Text = clickCount.ToString();       
}
```

Comment: no, I have two buttons with two different uses (to increase or decrease the count)

Comment: @Andrew you can have two buttonClick events, IncreaseButtonClick and DecreaseButtonClick.

Answer (score 1):

Each View (including UIButton) as an integer Tag property you can set to differentiate multiple Views from one another.  If you only want to have a single event handler for your Button you can utilize the Tag property.

```
IncreaseButton.Tag = 1;
DecreaseButton.Tag = -1;

partial void ButtonClick(NSObject sender)
{
  clickCount = clickCount + ((UIButton)sender).Tag;
  this.CountLabel.Text = clickCount.ToString();
}
```